# Asp.Net C# Entity Framework Distinct messes up Order

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, sql-order-by, distinct

I'm working with a ASP.Net MVC4 application using C3 and the Razor engine!
I have a database called builds which contains various columns, like version, creation date.

The database has doubles of Versions, i.e 4.0.230, 4.0.230, 4.0.229, 4.0.229. This is because to tell which version correspond to which environment. like if the Version isX64 etc.

So there is a Version for each environment.

I have a Entity Framework line asking to retrieve the last 10 builds:

```
var lastVersions = db.Builds.OrderByDescending(b => b.CreationDate).Take(10).Select(b=>b.Version);
```

so im ordering them by creation date and taking the last 10
it looks like this
4.0.240
4.0.240
4.0.239
4.0.239
4.0.238
etc

then with this line of code:

```
ViewBag.Versions = lastVersions.Distinct().ToArray();
```

I would like: [4.0.240, 4.0.239, 4.0.238, 4.0.237, 4.0.236]
but i get: [4.0.236, 4.0.237, 4.0.238, 4.0.239, 4.0.240]

Basically the OrderbyDescending is not working. 
Please Help 
All help is much appreciated! 
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your database, it looks like your OrderByDescending is indeed working, but you actually need to order twice.  Your first time, you order by creation date to get the most recent 10 builds, but then after the select, the order is not guaranteed anymore when stuffed into a var.  You must sort again by version number.  Assuming ViewBag.Versions is a string[], you could do:

`Array.Sort(ViewBag.Versions);`

or

`Array.Reverse(ViewBag.Versions);`

if they are in ascending order initially.